# Show $\mathbb{R}^2$ in dictionary order topology is metrizable

Tags: general-topology

The problem in the title is from Munkres book Topology. After trying it, I looked it on the internet to see if I had done it properly. I didnt't find any solution like mine, but I think mine is correct anyway,so it may be an alternative way to do it. Please tell me what you think, and if I messed up,because I don't see where I might have screwed up. So I came up with this metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the dictionary order topology:

\begin{equation}
d(a \times b, c \times d)= 1 + \min(|b-d|, 1) \end{equation}  if $a \neq c$

and \begin{equation} d(a \times b, c \times d)= \min(|b-d|, 1) \end{equation} if $a=c$

This is a metric, the first two properties are trivial, and the triangle inequality requires a bit more work because we have to consider different cases.

Now, given any open ball \begin{equation} B_d(a \times b, \epsilon)= (x \times y \in \mathbb{R}^2 | d( a \times b, x \times y) < \epsilon) \end{equation} I can always find an open set in the dictionary order topology that is contained in the ball:

Let $\delta < \epsilon$ then $(a \times b - \delta, a \times b + \delta)$ is in $B_d(a \times b, \epsilon)$.

Conversely, for any interval $(a \times b, c \times d)$ I can find an open ball contained in it:

Choose $B_d(a \times b + \epsilon, \epsilon)$, if $a=c$ we just have to be careful with the size of $\epsilon$ in order for $b + \epsilon$ not be larger tha $d$.

Done. Thanks for any comments.

Comment: I think your metric works fine. However, there are the details of how to prove that the topologies are equal. It's not enough to "find an open ball contained in". What you must do to prove that one topology is equal to another is the following: Take a set $U$ that is open in one set. Then for _every_ $x\in U$, show that there is a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ that is open in the second topology and contained in $U$. Then vice versa, of course.